# SQL Select add up rows

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to select an add up simular rows bases on one field

```
product    amount
abc        2
abc        3
def        2
def        1
```

and I want as a result

```
Produkt    Amount
abc        5
def        3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack overflow is for help not for complete work.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sum` aggregate function with the `group by` clause:

```
select product, sum(amount) from tbl group by product
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the table by the product and then select the name and use the aggragate function of SUM.  Your query for this should look something like this:

```
SELECT product, SUM(amount) 
FROM <TABLENAME>
GROUP BY product
```